# Variance of Multimodal Generalized von Mises Distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, von-mises-distribution

How do you calculate the variance of a Multimodal Generalized von Mises (MGvM) distribution? Given its complexity with multiple modes and asymmetry, I'm looking for:

Any formula or method to calculate its variance considering concentration parameters, weights, and mode positions.

###### [definition](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343164673_Multimodal_exponential_families_of_circular_distributions_with_application_to_daily_peak_hours_of_PM25_level_in_a_large_city):

[image]

Appreciate any guidance or references to tackle this for circular data analysis.

Comment: Should we assume you are interested in a symbolic approximation rather than specifying the parameters and performing numerical integration?

Comment: @JimB yes. in fact I want to compute MSE of unbiased estimator for theta distributed by MGvM. that is variance of this estimator.

Answer (score 0):

While I suspect that there is no nice closed-form for any of the moments (and also the constant of integration), until someone comes up with a good solution having a numerical approximation as a check on that solution should be useful.

Here is an implementation in *Mathematica* that gets you the constant of integration, the mean and variance, the modes and anti-modes, and a plot of the density.  (This can certainly be done in R and/or Python.)

```
f[μ_, κ_] := Module[{const, mean, variance, modes, plot},
  (* Constant of integration *)
  const = NIntegrate[xp[Sum[κ[[s]] Cos[s (θ - μ[[s]])], {s, Length[μ]}]], {θ, -π, π}];

  (* Mean and variance *)
  mean = NIntegrate[θ Exp[Sum[κ[[s]] Cos[s (θ - μ[[s]])], {s, Length[μ]}]], {θ, -π, π}]/const;
  variance = NIntegrate[(θ - mean)^2  Exp[Sum[κ[[s]] Cos[s (θ - μ[[s]])], {s,  Length[μ]}]], {θ, -π, π}]/const;

  (* Modes and antimodes *)
  modes = θ /. Solve[{Sum[s  κ[[s]]  Sin[s (θ - μ[[s]])], {s, Length[μ]}] ==  0, -π <= θ <= π}, θ] // N;

  (* Plot of density *)
  plot = Show[Plot[Exp[Sum[κ[[s]] Cos[s (θ - μ[[s]])], {s, Length[μ]}]]/const, {θ, -π, π}, 
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"θ", "Probability density"},
    PlotRange -> {All, {0, All}}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangeClipping -> False],
    ListPlot[{#, 0} & /@ modes]];
  
  (* Return results *)
  {const, mean, variance, modes, plot}]

f[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}]

(* {58.0038, 0.768388, 0.972282, {-2.28195, -1.12763, -0.141593, 0.973666, 2.01917, 2.85038}, *)
```

[image: Density of theta given specific parameters]